# Problem installing virtualbox on ubuntu 9.04 

Tags: apt, virtualbox, 9.04

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to install software or upgrade from old unsupported release?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/91815/how-to-install-software-or-upgrade-from-old-unsupported-release)

I'm using ubuntu 9.04. From last few days I'm trying to install a virtualbox,but i can't. I went to this link for virtualbox. https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Download_Old_Builds_3_0
Found the virtualbox for my version. After downloading it in xp i restarted my pc and opened ubuntu. While installing by package installer there is a problem. But the status giving a massage everytime I'm trying to install.it saying "Error: Dependency is not satisfiable: libcurl3 (>=7.16.2-1)".
Here is an icon named "install package" but its hidden. I don't know what's the problem.I'm new to ubuntu,pls try to help me.

Answer (score 0):

First open the place where you downloaded Virtual Box package.deb file.

Open terminal

Type

```
sudo dpkg -i
```

Drag and drop virtualbox package.deb file into terminal with using mouse.
Come back to terminal and press enter. 
Give password and virtualbox will be installed.

Comment: I don't know how to use terminal.is there any way to learn terminal?

Comment: It is very simple.Pres ctrl+alt+t to open it. You have just write command given above.